# Как распечатать JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, печать, jpanel

Пишу программу по учету заказов одного предприятия. Есть форма, которая по сути есть отчет, то есть на нее добавляется различная информация. Мне необходимо сделать возможность ее распечатать. Каким образом можно это реализовать? Я так понимаю, нужно распечатать именно JPanel, так как на ней все хранится. Форма наследуется от JDialog. 
Погуглил, нашел решения, но они все связаны с JFrame, соответственно свою JPanel туда пихнуть не могу. Еще пишут что нужно как-то переработать класс Printable, но тут я не совсем разобрался. 
Может стоит вручную сделать форму и пихнуть все на JFrame?

Comment: Вы видели [это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703329/how-to-print-jpanel-in-java)?

Comment: @AntonSorokin видел, но к сожалению не разобрался. Я так понимаю, там представлен класс Printer? внутри него все действия происходят

Comment: а можно сделать скриншот через Alt+PrintScreen и распечатать само окно?